# CONAN_PKG::<PKG-NAME> not found when using cmake to generate build target

Tags: cmake, conan

`CONAN_PKG::spdlog` is not found when using CMake to generate build configurations.

The conan package I use is *spdlog/1.3.1@bincrafters/stable*.
I have a CMake executable target which references a conan package `spdlog`. I am getting this error message:

```
[build] CMake Error at src/apps/ResultObserver/CMakeLists.txt:10 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
[build]   Target "ResultObserver" links to target "CONAN_PKG::spdlog" but the target
[build]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[build]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I have these lines in my CMakeLists.txt.

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

ADD_EXECUTABLE(ResultObserver src/ResultObserver.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ResultObserver CONAN_PKG::spdlog)
```

Also, after installing the conan package, the *conanbuildinfo.cmake* file is generated in the build directory.

I checked inside the file. It contains these lines.

```
    add_library(CONAN_PKG::spdlog INTERFACE IMPORTED)

    # Property INTERFACE_LINK_FLAGS do not work, necessary to add to INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES
    set_property(TARGET CONAN_PKG::spdlog PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES .........
```

Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for the `TARGETS` approach. You need to pass `TARGETS` to `conan_basic_setup()` to generate `CONAN_PKG::`. Otherwise, only `${CONAN_LIBS}` will be available.

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(ResultObserver src/ResultObserver.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ResultObserver CONAN_PKG::spdlog)
```

More info about the CMake target generator is here:
https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html#targets-approach